# KDE shows higher count as compared acutal pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting started with Titanic Spaceship dataset. (https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/spaceship-titanic)

I am trying to understand the effect of the foodcourt feature on the transported result. On plotting a violin plot, I see that the number of passengers who did not use the foodcourt (0 expense) and did not get transported is higher as compared to the number of passengers who did not use the foodcourt (0 expense) and get transported.

However, when I use the following code, I see that the passengers who did not use the foodcourt and did not get transported are lesser as compared to the number of passengers who did not use the foodcourt and got transported.

```py
temp = df_train.loc[df_train['FoodCourt'] == 0]
temp_0 = temp.loc[temp['Transported'] == False][enter image description here][1]
temp_1 = temp.loc[temp['Transported'] == True]

print(len(temp_0))
print(len(temp_1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the same code that you posted, the results I got from the violin plot (and swarm plot) are identical to the data.
Slicing the dataframe to the passengers that got transported and not transported:

```
temp_0 = temp[temp["Transported"] == True]
temp_1 = temp[temp["Transported"] == False]
```

The lengths of these dataframes are:

```
temp_0.shape[0] #3224
temp_1.shape[0] #2232
```

The plot is:
[image: plot]

If you want the width of the violin to scale up using the number of observations in each group, add scale="count" argument as the following:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
plot = sns.violinplot(y="FoodCourt", x="Transported", data=data, scale="count")
plt.show()
```

The result:
[image: plot2]

Just note that, it is better to create a countplot, to see how many observation we have in each subgroup, like this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
plot = sns.countplot(x=temp["Transported"])
plt.bar_label(plot.containers[0])
plt.show()
```

The result:
[image: countplot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My confusion is what does your first picture represent? For passengers that are not transported, shouldn't the width of the violin curve at 0 be less than the width of the violin curve of passengers that are transported? Like we are getting in your second picture.

Comment: @UmerSherdil violinplots and boxplots, are meant to show the distribution of data rather than the number of observations, in the second plot, I have added an argument that will scale the width of the violin to the number of observations (which is not considered by default), that is why it is appearing to be wider. Generally, you don't want to compare number of observations using violinplots, instead use countplot, but if you insist on visualizing distribution and number of observations in the same plot, use swarmplot, because then, data points won't overlap (it takes longer to run though).

Comment: Thank you so much. It answers my question.

Comment: @UmerSherdil Happy to help. If this answers your issue, please mark it as accepted.